# connect access database with crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm new to the vb.net and crystal report. I tried to connect crystal report with access database table. I wrote a sql quary to filter data and those data display on datagridview successfully. I want display those data in crystal report also. but it shows datagridview in nicely but it shows an error in crystal report loading view. it shows as "load report failed".
can someone assist to sort this issue please. following is my code.

<
ComboBox1.Text = "2023" And ComboBox2.Text = "2"

```
        Try
            Dim sql As String
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim cryRpt8 As New ReportDocument
            Dim CrTables As Tables
            Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
            Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo

            con.Open()


                sql = "select r.Department, r.officerName, b.book_ID, b.Requisition_Date, b.title, b.Authors, b.edition, b.Quantity, b.pdf_availability, b.Book_type, q.bidder1, q.bidder2, q.bidder3, q.up1currancy, q.up2currancy, q.up3currancy, q.unitprice_b1, q.unitprice_b2, q.unitprice_b3, q.ac1currancy, q.ac2currancy, q.ac3currancy, q.ac1, q.ac2, q.ac3, q.fa1currancy, q.fa2currancy, q.fa3currancy, q.fa1, q.fa2, q.fa3, q.committee_No FROM ((reqesition r INNER JOIN books b ON b.reqesitionID=r.reqesitionID) INNER JOIN quotation q ON q.BookID=b.book_ID)where q.committee_No LIKE '%" & 2 & "%' and b.Requisition_Date LIKE  '%" & 2023 & "%' "
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = sql
                poppp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

                da.SelectCommand = cmd
                da.Fill(dt)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

            cryRpt8.Load(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "E:\SLIIT\Final Book purchasing System\Final Book purchasing System\CrystalReport74.rpt")

            With ConnectionInfo

                .DatabaseName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "E:\SLIIT\Database1.accdb"

                .UserID = "Admin"
                .Password = " "
            End With

            CrTables = cryRpt8.Database.Tables

            For Each CrTable In CrTables
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
            Next


            cryRpt8.SetDataSource(dt)
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt8
            CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()



        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try
```

> 